# C: shutdown multithreaded program

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

The idea is to have one main thread which starts multiple worker threads. There is no clear way to exit the program except from sending a signal. But the program should also cleanly exit in case an error occurs, anywhere.

I try to show what I have so far. The headers are not shown but It should be clear without them. We have a main.c with the main function where everything begins, worker.c with the abstraction for thread management and object.c, one specific implementation for a worker thread. There will be multiple different implementations, but all with the same structure (that is, a `process()` function with a `while(running)` loop).

main.c

```
#include <signal.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 5

volatile static sig_atomic_t running = 1;
volatile static int exit_code = 0;

void shutdown(int s)
{
    running = 0;
    exit_code = s;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = shutdown;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, 0);

    thread_obj *threads[NUM_THREADS];
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
        threads[i] = worker_new();
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; ++i) {
        pthread_join(threads[i]->worker, NULL);
        theads[i]->free();
        free(threads[i]);
    }

    return exit_code;
}
```

worker.c

```
#include <pthread.h>

struct thread_object {
    pthread_t worker;
    int *running:
    void *obj;
    void (*process)(void *obj, int *running);
    void (*free)(void *obj);
}:

void *thread_func(void *obj)
{
    struct thread_object *tmp = obj;
    tmp->process(tmp->obj, tmp->running):
    return;
}

struct thread_object *worker_new(void *obj)
{
   struct thread_object *tmp = malloc(sizeof(*tmp));
   tmp->obj = obj;
   tmp->running = running;
   tmp->process = obj->process;
   tmp->free = obj->free;
   pthread_create(&(tmp->worker), NULL, thread_func, obj);
   return tmp;
}
```

object.c

```
#include "main.h"

void process(void *obj, int *running)
{
    struct special_object *tmp = obj;
    while(*running) {
        // do something
        if(error) {
            kill(getpid(), SIGTERM);
            break;
        }
    }
    // cleanup tasks
}
```

Now the question is, what would be the cleanest, fastest and most portable way to implement this in C? The two main points again: Stop all threads and shut down gracefully if a) a signal like SIGINT is received or b) at least one worker encounters an error.

Edit: I tried to include the suggestions, but now there are some follow-up questions:

- Is pthread_join more/less/equally efficient as a sleep? The main
  thread has nothing to do while the workers run, only catch signals,
  and I want to avoid as many wakeups as possible.
- Consider the following: We catch SIGTERM signals and the handler sets the 
  `running` variable to false. Will this skip the loop (reliably)?

`kill(getpid(), SIGTERM);
while (*running) {;}`

Comment: 'Stop all threads and shut down gracefully' well, you should understand that this is, in the general case, not possible with generally available languages/OS, eg. C on Windows/Linux. If it is at all possible, you should design so that 'Stop all threads and shut down gracefully' is not required for correct operation upon process termination/restart.

Comment: It looks like the code you've shown already meets most of the requirements; is there some particular way it falls short?  (if you want the shutdown sequence to also occur whenever a particular thread encounters an error, the easiest way to do that is just have the thread call e.g. kill(getpid(), SIGINT), so that the thread sends a signal to its containing process; then the normal signal-handling sequence will occur as usual, so that the process exits in a controlled fashion)

Comment: One thing I am unhappy with is the main loop. I could probably use `pause()` instead of `sleep()`, if the error-encountering sends a signal this loop should break.
It is not enough to simply call `exit()` as I've encountered issues with libraries I am using that at least some cleanup is absolutly necessary. I am happy with a clean solution that will work 99% of the time. The code I've shown is only a design approach and I was hoping for feedback, where I can improve things or where might be errors.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the sleep loop is unneeded, the join should be enough.

In other use cases you could look into waitpid with a pid of -1 to get status from any thread that has something to say.

Also a semaphore could in some cases be useful if some threads stop before others, either do something after a thread post or wait until all have posted.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to include your suggestions. See my edit. Also, could you please elaborate under what circumstances a semaphore is neccessary here? I can't make any assumptions when what threads end, and the threads are independent of each other. Setting the global run variable should be an atomic operation so I currently don't see any need for semaphores, but I may miss something.

Comment: A semaphore can wait for a time or until a given number of postings to it, or just handle each posting and evaluate if its time to shut down.